# Where is the "Wonder Woman dancing" scene from?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

[image: Backstage footage of Gal Gadot dressed as Wonder Woman dancing and spinning around as the camera zooms out]

I have seen this awesome gif of Wonder Woman lots of times, but I don't know its origin.

So far Gal Galot has appeared as Wonder Woman only in 3 movies viz. *Batman v Superman*, *Wonder Woman*, *Justice League*. And, as far as I can recall, she was always in serious scenes in all these movies. When could she go for this cheerful spin?

There are other possibilities I can imagine:

- CGI. Hard to believe because of cost, but you can never underestimate fans.
- Gal Galot's home made video.
- Fun video shoot on movie set. If yes, which movie set?

Answer (score 10):

It's an outtake from *Batman vs Superman*, though I'm not sure where it was originally published. It *looks* like a photo shoot during the *Batman vs Superman* filming (it predates *Wonder Woman*) but I don't recognize the building in the set.

Here's a longer clip which appears to be the end of the actual shoot, followed by her dancing once the scene was over:

Comment: How did you come up with *Batman v Superman*?

Comment: It was an educated guess. I found a video of this on YouTube dated June 2016; Wonder Woman was just in the middle of filming then, so I thought it unlikely something behind the scenes like this would be allowed to be published that early. June 2016 was when BvS was getting it's home release, though.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen anything authoritatively backgrounding this, but it looks to me like just some goofing off on the set (probably of *Wonder Woman*, and possibly in reference to how the Wonder Woman of the old TV series would change into her superhero garb (like [this](https://youtu.be/knEy_qqrxJU?t=6)), the kind of thing that could show up in a blooper-reel some day (like [these](http://www.zimbio.com/For+The+Win/articles/cGHnwMODZHc/Gal+Gadot+Posted+Bloopers+Wonder+Woman+Way) and some of [these](https://www.buzzfeed.com/lyapalater/if-this-post-doesnt-make-you-fall-in-love-with-gal-gadot?utm_term=.upvZlMJ96#.npp72LBOY)).